# Arithmetic progression in a subset of $\mathbb N$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ramsey-theory

What non-trivial sufficient and/or necessary conditions are there for existence an arithmetic progression (finite or infinite length) in an infinite subset of $\mathbb N$.

Comment: Here's one, "there exists $q>0$ and $k$ such that for all $n\geq k$, $nq\in A$".

Comment: I assume you mean infinite arithmetic progression rather than arbitrarily long ones?

Comment: My statement above needs a minor correction, as the progression could start at some arbitrary number $d$, so it should be that for some $d$, $nq+d\in A$.

Comment: @Asaf: Pretty sure that's necessary, too. ;-)

Comment: @Cameron: Which is why it's only a comment! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you know all of this, but:

- [Szemerédi's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Szemer%C3%A9di%27s_theorem) gives a sufficient condition: It suffices that the set (call it $A$) has positive upper density, that is, $$ \limsup_n \frac{|A\cap[1,n]|}n>0. $$ This improved [van der Waerden's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waerden%27s_theorem) that ensures that for any $A\subseteq\mathbb N$, either it or its complement has arbitrarily large progressions.
- The Green-Tao theorem shows that Szemerédi's condition is not necessary: The primes have arbitrarily long progressions, and density zero. But their argument identifies a strengthening of Szemerédi's result. As they put it, "any subset of a sufficiently pseudorandom set of positive relative density contains progressions of arbitrary length." For the precise (somewhat technical) statement, see Theorem 3.5 in their paper *[The primes contain arbitrarily long arithmetic progressions](http://arxiv.org/abs/math.NT/0404188)*.
- The [Erdős conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s_conjecture_on_arithmetic_progressions) would extend both results: It suffices that $$\sum_{n\in A} \frac1n=+\infty.$$ This is currently completely open: We do not even know that such an $A$ contains $3$-term progressions.
- Some results are known in term of descriptive set theory. The point is that the sets $B$ that do not contain arbitrarily large progressions form an ideal (that is, if $\mathcal I$ is the class of such sets $B$, then if $C\subseteq B\in\mathcal I$, then also $C\in\mathcal I$, and if $B,D\in\mathcal I$, then $B\cup D\in\mathcal I$). This ideal is a Borel ideal (identifying it with a subset of $2^{\mathbb N}$, endowed with the usual product topology), and therefore suitable to techniques of descriptive set theory and set theoretic topology. See for example these [slides](http://home.zcu.cz/~flaskova/research/KielceSUMTOPO-handout.pdf) by Jana Flašková. There is in fact a sizable literature on ultrafilters and their connection to van der Waerden's theorem.